# Android + Use LoaderManager with an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android

I might be way off here, but I have an ArrayAdapter managing static data for a ListFragment.  Very simple stuff.  However, I'm interested in taking advantage of the new LoaderManager class.  Can I still use my ArrayAdapter and write my own loader?  The documents seem to suggest this is true:

*"...the most common use of this is with a CursorLoader, however applications are free to write their own loaders for loading other types of data."*

If this is the case, how might I work with the overridden LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks interface methods?

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {return null;}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are creating a new type of Loader you might need to use a different type for the data rather than Cursor (unless your new loader also returns Cursors).

Your callbacks should look something like

```
@Override
public Loader<MyDataType> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new MyCustomLoader(...);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<MyDataType> loader, MyDataType data) {
    myArrayAdapter.add(data.something()); // etc
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<MyDataType> loader) {
     myArrayAdapter.clear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, could you point me in the direction of a good example or tutorial showing the creation of the custom Loader?  I can't seem to find a thing on custom Loaders and Android.  Thanks!

Comment: Where would I instantiate the new Adapter, and when would I set it?

Comment: The [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) documentation contains an example of how to implement a custom loader.

Comment: Where do I create the ProgressBar?

Comment: You can both instantiate your Adapter and assign it to a View in your activities onCreate method

Comment: This is too short to make an edit, but would you mind changing onLoadFInished to onLoadFinished? And onLoaderRest to onLoaderReset.